# ¿Cómo mostrar un archivo pdf con django?

Tags: django, postgresql, pdf, archivo

He estado intentando abrir archivos que tengo guardados de forma local, la dirección de dichos archivos las tengo almacenadas en una tabla de postgreSQL.

El problema que tengo es que al momento de llamar el archivo me dice e no lo encuentra.
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Archivos/MedSuperior/Pago.pdf

El contenido de mi template es el siguiente:

```
    {% block content %}
  <table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Solicitud</th>
        <th>A1</th>
        <th>A2</th>
        <th>A3</th>
        <th>A4</th>
        <th>A5</th>
        <th>A6</th>
        <th>A7</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for book in books %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ book.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ book.id_solicitud }}</td>
          <td><a href="{{ book.pago.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank">Ver pago PDF</a></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Mi modelo es:

```
class CMedSuperior(models.Model):
id_solicitud = models.ForeignKey('Solicitud',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
pago = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/MedSuperior/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Y el método donde mando a llamar el template es:

```
def file_list(request, folio):
file = CMedSuperior.objects.filter(id=folio)
print(file)
return render(request, 'revisionMedSuperior.html', {
    'books': file
})
```

Me base en este proyecto para hacerlo:
https://github.com/sibtc/django-upload-example

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO

Lo resolví analizando un poco más el proyecto en el que me base y concluí que el error estaba en una configuración que se encontraba el el archivo urls.py del proyecto. Me faltaba lo siguiente:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
...
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```